# Asp.net Chart doesn't work in Page_Load when using LoadControl + UserControl

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a UserControl which contains an asp.net Chart.  If I reference the user control statically in the page, the chart displays, i.e.:

```
<uc:UserControl1 id="UserControl1" runat="server" />
```

However, if I load the user control from the codebehind in the Page_Load event, the Chart does not display:

```
Panel1.Controls.Add(this.LoadControl("UserControl1.ascx"));
```

I have other controls in the user control such as a GridView, and both of the above methods work for those controls.  The only control that isn't working is the asp.net Chart control.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate dynamically created user controls in the code behind, you still have to set the reference is the aspx page.

```
<%@ Reference Control="UserControl.ascx" %>
```

Comment: Right, I am already doing that, the problem isn't that the user control isn't displaying, it's that every control within the user control works except for the asp Chart.